# Laravel/Passport Do I really need to register Passport::routes() for a simple CRUD API?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I registered `Passport::routes();` in the boot method of AuthServiceProvider, but I don't seem to be using any of the routes it registers.

Do I need them?  What are they used for?  Can't I just use my custom routes that map to a custom controller for login, register and logout methods?

Comment: if you going to use Passport as an 0Auth server absolutely.  If you are not going to then no, but keep in mind you will need some type of authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(EDITED) No, you do not need to register `Passport::routes()` in AuthServiceProvider if you don't use them.  The following custom controller logic (adapted from https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876) will still register a new user and return a valid token using Passport's built-in OAuth2 server:

```php
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
        'name' => 'required', 
        'email' => 'required|email', 
        'password' => 'required', 
        'retype_password' => 'required|same:password', 
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) { 
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);            
    }

    $user = User::firstOrCreate(
        ['email' => $request->email],
        ['name' => $request->name, 'password' => bcrypt($request->password)]
    ); 

    $response = [
        'token' => $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken
    ];

    return response()->json($response, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

In the example above, `createToken($key)` comes from the `HasApiTokens` trait included with Passport which will return the token, regardless of whether you register the routes.  (Thanks to [patricus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3583182/patricus) for correcting my initial answer.)

Comment: The `createToken()` method interacts with the OAuth server to create a personal access token, but it doesn't do it through the routes. The `Passport::routes()` are not needed for the code you have posted.

Comment: @patricus you're right, thanks!  my api routes using this controller logic still work after commenting out the route registration.  updating my answer